# Отправка письма другому серверу

Tags: php, smtp, сокет

Доброго времени суток товарищи! Давайте представим, что почтовый сервер с именем [pwon.pp.ua](http://pwon.pp.ua) получил письмо от клиента пользователя htaccess@pwon.pp.ua и собирается передать это письмо пользователю arsh-andrej@mail.ru .

И сразу вопрос : **как осуществить обмен почтой между серверами, как должны общаться для этого сервера между собою?**

Я написал код на PHP и даже успел немного пообщаться с почтовым сервером [mail.ru](http://mail.ru)

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
#
$opensocket_0       =   fsockopen('smtp.mail.ru', 25, $errorcode, $errortext);
#
if ($opensocket_0 !== false) {
    //echo 'Подключено';
    echo fgets($opensocket_0, 10000)."<br />\n";
    #
    fwrite($opensocket_0, 'HELO mail.pwon.pp.ua'."\n");
    #
    echo fgets($opensocket_0, 10000)."<br />\n";
    #
    fwrite($opensocket_0, 'MAIL FROM: <htaccess@pwon.pp.ua>'."\n");
    #
    echo fgets($opensocket_0, 10000)."<br />\n";
    #
    fwrite($opensocket_0, 'RCPT TO: <arsh-andrej@mail.ru>'."\n");
    #
    echo fgets($opensocket_0, 10000)."<br />\n";
    #
} else {
    var_dump($opensocket_0);
}
?>
```

И вот что я получил в ответ :

> 220 [smtp16.mail.ru](http://smtp16.mail.ru) ESMTP ready 250
>
> [smtp16.mail.ru](http://smtp16.mail.ru) 250 2.0.0 OK 550
>
> not local sender over smtp

**Как передать сообщение от клиента к серверу мне знать пока не нужно, мне интересно узнать как передать письмо от сервера к серверу.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена, вспомнил, что у меня на компе где то валялся старый почтовый сервер, похимичил с ним, вот что получилось :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
#
$opensocket_0       =   fsockopen('mail.pwon.pp.ua', 25, $errorcode, $errortext);
#
if ($opensocket_0 !== false) {
    //echo 'Подключено';
    echo fgets($opensocket_0, 10000)."<br />\n";
    #
    fwrite($opensocket_0, 'HELO 192.168.1.2'."\n");
    #
    echo fgets($opensocket_0, 10000)."<br />\n";
    #
    fwrite($opensocket_0, 'MAIL FROM: <htaccess@t.pwon.pp.ua>'."\n");
    #
    echo fgets($opensocket_0, 10000)."<br />\n";
    #
    fwrite($opensocket_0, 'RCPT TO: <admin@mail.pwon.pp.ua>'."\n");
    #
    echo fgets($opensocket_0, 10000)."<br />\n";
    #
    fwrite($opensocket_0, 'DATA'."\n");
    #
    echo fgets($opensocket_0, 10000)."<br />\n";
    #
    fwrite($opensocket_0, 'From: htaccess@t.pwon..p.ua'."\n".'To: admin@mail.pwon.pp.ua'."\n".'Subject: theme olololo'."\n\n\n");
    #
    fwrite($opensocket_0, 'Hola idioto'."\n");
    #
    fwrite($opensocket_0, "\n");
    #
    fwrite($opensocket_0, '.'."\n");
    #
    echo fgets($opensocket_0, 10000)."<br />\n";
    #
    fwrite($opensocket_0, 'QUIT'."\n");
    #
    echo fgets($opensocket_0, 10000)."<br />\n";
    #
    fclose($opensocket_0);
} else {
    var_dump($opensocket_0);
}
?>
```

И вот чат скрипта-сервера с сервером :

> 220 [192.168.1.2] Courier Mail Server 2.07 ESMTP service ready
>
> 250 [192.168.1.2] greets 192.168.1.2
>
> 250 OK, sender -
>
> 250 OK, recipient -
>
> 354 Send data. End with CRLF.CRLF
>
> 250 OK
>
> 221 Service closing transmission channel